# @Resource(name="jms/StockQueue", type=javax.jms.Queue) @Stateless public class StockServiceBean{} JNDI lookup does not work

Tags: queue, ejb, jms, jndi

I am trying to run the example from page 281 of EJB 3.2 specification but it produces an error. Briefly, I created a queue jms/StockQueue in Glassfish 4 and I can inject a reference to it with @Resource(lookup = "jms/StockQueue"). So my stateless bean MyBean successfully gets reference to the queue.

```
@Stateless
public class MyBean {

@Resource(lookup = "jms/StockQueue")
private Queue queue;

public void sendMessage() {
    System.out.println(queue);
}
}
```

But StockServiceBean from the specification does not get the reference to the queue.

```
@Resource(name = "jms/StockQueue", type = javax.jms.Queue.class)
@Stateless
public class StockServiceBean {
public void processStockInfo() {
    try {
        Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
        System.out.print(initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env/jms/StockQueue"));
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Instead it produces an error:

```
  SEVERE:   javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/jms/StockQueue' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: No object bound for java:comp/env/jms/StockQueue [Root exception is java.lang.NullPointerException]]
```

Strangely, if instead of Queue, I lookup ConnectionFactory, the example works as expected.
Could anyone help me to run this example? I would appreciate your suggestions. Thank you.
Best regards,
Marian

Answer (score 0):

i had similar problem with connectionFactory / @Resource  / @Stateless. At deploiement the @Resource injection tries to inject on my service bean but this last is not yet instanciated by Weld (because he has a @Dependent scope)

i resolved it doing a manual look up on the function using the connectionFactory and it works

Also see this : https://blogs.oracle.com/chengfang/entry/do_s_and_don_ts